# Which is the best design for a MongoDB database model?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I feel like the MVP of my current database needs some design changes. The number of users is growing quite fast and we are having bad performances in some requests. I also want to get rid of all the DBRef we used.

Our current model can be summarized as follow :

- A company can have multiple employees (thousands)
- A company can have multiple teams (hundreds)
- An employee can be part of a team
- A company can have multiple devices (thousands)
- An employee is affected to multiple devices

Our application displays in different pages :

- The company data
- The users
- The devices
- The teams

I guess I have different options, but I'm not familiar enough with MongoDB to make the best decision.

**Option 1**

Do not embed and use list of ids for one to many relationships.

```json
// Company document
{
    "companyName": "ACME",
    "users": [ObjectId(user1), ObjectId(user2)],
    "teams": [ObjectId(team1), ObjectId(team2)],
    "devices": [ObjectId(device1), ObjectId(device2)]
}

// User Document
{
    "userName": "Foo",
    "devices": [ObjectId(device2)]
}

// Team Document
{
    "teamName": "Foo",
    "users": [ObjectId(user1)]
}

// Device Document
{
    "deviceName": "Foo"
}
```

**Option 2**

Embed data and duplicate informations.

```json
// User Document
{
    "companyName": "ACME",
    "userName": "Foo",
    "team": {
        "teamName": "Foo"
    },
    "device": {
        "deviceName": "Foo"
    }
}

// Team Document
{
    "teamName": "Foo"
    "companyName": "ACME",
    "users": [
        {
            "userName": "Foo"
        }
    ]
}

// Device Document
{
    "deviceName": "Foo",
    "companyName": "ACME",
    "user": {
        "userName": "Foo"
    }
}
```

**Option 3**

Do not embed and use id for one to one relationship.

```json
// Company document
{
    "companyName": "ACME"
}

// User Document
{
    "userName": "Foo",
    "company": ObjectId(company),
    "team": ObjectId(team1)
}

// Team Document
{
    "teamName": "Foo",
    "company": ObjectId(company)
}

// Device Document
{
    "deviceName": "Foo",
    "company": ObjectId(company),
    "user": ObjectId(user1)
}
```

MongoDB recommends to embed data as much as possible but I don't think it can be possible to embed all data in the company document. A company can have multiple devices or users and I believe it can grow too big.

I'm switching from SQL to NoSQL and I think I haven't figured it out by myself yet !

Thanks !

Comment: Mongo would traditionally recommend denormalising all the data.

Comment: Usually it is a poor design when you move from SQL to NoSQL and transform each table to a collection one-by-one. We would need more details, offhand I would say one collection for user/team/company and one collection for devices.

Answer (score 0):

MongodB provides you with a feature which is handling unstructured data.
**Every database can contain collection which in turn can contain documents.**
Moreover, you cannot use joins in mongodB. So, storing information in one company model is a better choice because you wont be needed join in that scenario.
One more thing, You dont need to embed all the models **For example : You can get user and device both from company table, so why embedding users and device as well?**